# SQL injection with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 and use the following code for calling a stored procedure. Please advice me, whether this code can be attacked via SQL injection.

```
DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>("Name Of SP", params object[] parameters).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it *can*, sql injection occurs when there is any type of string concatenation, if the stored procedure does string concatenation to execute a command inside, you would still be vulnerable